Audio degraded on one device since upgrading to Pipewire 1.0
Since upgrading to Pipewire 1.0.7 I've been experiencing very low sound quality specifically on one of my audio devices specifically with some apps. At this point I do not know what I can do further to investigate and figure out what is happening and kindly request your help.
Sorry for the very long post but I thought I should include as much detail as possible in case something is useful. Likelier than not, somebody will see the logs from journalctl in the TL;DR below and know right away what I should try :)
TL;DR

Pipewire sending audio streams to 2 USB audio devices using a combined sink.
One device sound quality always good. One device plays very degraded audio with some programs, typically games running under wine, but never reproducible with some other programs. Also reproducible most of the time but not 100%, sometimes audio will be good even with the bad programs.
Journal contains many lines like spa.alsa: hw:Audiop: follower avail:770 delay:770 target:640 thr:128, resync (249 suppressed) when the issue happens.
Tried increasing headroom and period-size alsa properties with pw-cli, to no avail.
Not sure what to try next.

Full details below.
The symptom
Very poor sound quality out of the speakers, only when some programs are running, only most of the time. The audio could be described as crackling but not stuttering, leading me to believe (together with my investigations, see below) this is likely not a buffer underflow issue. The sound is not degraded enough as to be unrecognizable but sufficiently to make speech hard if not impossible to understand.

This only happens with some programs, typically games running under wine.
This only happens on this device, not on the headphones.
Even with the programs where it does happen, it only happens about 80~90% of the time, sometimes it will be fine. Quitting and restarting the program sometimes will change whether it occurs. I've also seen programs randomly start degrading or recover while they were playing audio but I'm not sure what the trigger might be.
Many programs never have the issue such as playing audio/video with VLC, or in Chrome using Youtube or so, when they are alone playing audio. However, if a program with the issue is currently running and has degraded quality, the audio of all apps playing at the same time will also be degraded, even if the offending program is muted.

Machine
Machine is running an AMD Ryzen 7 7700 on an Asus ROG Strix X670E-F motherboard, running Debian testing (trixie). It's running KDE 5.27 on Wayland. It has two audio devices in use :

The onboard audio on the motherboard, an Asus SupremeFX.

This is detected as USB audio : 0b05:1a52 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB Audio
This is the device that my speakers are connected to, and that I am having trouble with.


A pair of USB headphones, 046d:0af7 Logitech, Inc. PRO X 2 LIGHTSPEED

While this is almost certainly irrelevant, the machine also has two audio devices on the graphics card, which I disable with wireplumber because I don't use them. For the record, the card is an ASRock Radeon RX7600, which exposes Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 31 HDMI/DP Audio and Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller.
The audio setup is running Pipewire with Wireplumber over ALSA, and Pipewire-pulse.
When this started happening
This started happening as I upgraded from Debian Stable to Debian Testing a few weeks ago. This upgraded

The kernel from 6.1.90-1 to 6.7.12-1
Pipewire from 0.3.65-3+deb12u1 to 1.0.7-1
Wireplumber from 0.4.13-1 to 0.5.3-1.
As I upgraded the full distro many other packages have been upgraded at the same time, though I'm not sure what else might be relevant to my issue.

With the upgrade to wireplumber > 0.5, I had to upgrade my old wireplumber setup files from lua to the new JSON format. These files assign nicknames to devices for ease of use ("node.description" "node.nick") and reverse left and right on the problematic device (audio.position = "FR,FL") since speaker makers still won't sell speakers with decently long cables :/ This is almost certainly irrelevant though.
The setup as seen from Pulse, and what I could learn from that
From a Pulseaudio point of view, there are three sinks on the machine :

The headphones (Logitech pro X 2 as described above)
The speaker (Asus USB audio as described above)
A combined sink, which outputs to both.

I normally play all audio through the combined sink.

If I run a problematic program (e.g. Tetris effect, which exhibits the symptom), outputting to the combined sink, the sound is poor on the speakers and good on the headphones.
If I run a non-problematic program (e.g. VLC) outputting to the combined sink the sound is always good on both devices.
If I run both Tetris effect and VLC on the combined sink, the sound of both is distorted on the speakers but not on the headphones. This is true even if the problematic program is muted with pactl set-sink-input-mute, as long as the stream is open.
If I move Tetris effect to output to the headphones with the KDE mixer applet, immediately the sound from VLC becomes good.
If I move Tetris effect to output directly on the speakers, the problem still reproduces. It also still distorts the sound from VLC playing through the combined sink.
If I move Tetris effect to the combined sink and VLC to the speakers, both audio are still distorted.

The sink as seen by pactl list sinks looks like this :
Sink #63
        State: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFi__hw_Audio__sink
        Description: Enceintes
        Driver: PipeWire
        Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-right,front-left
        Owner Module: 4294967295
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-right: 62259 /  95% / -1.34 dB,   front-left: 62259 /  95% / -1.34 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFi__hw_Audio__sink.monitor
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Properties:
                alsa.card = "3"
                alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.components = "USB0b05:1a52"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                alsa.id = "Audio"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:11:00.0-6, high speed"
                alsa.mixer_device = "_ucm0005.hw:Audio"
                alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
                alsa.name = "USB Audio"
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                api.alsa.card.longname = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:11:00.0-6, high speed"
                api.alsa.card.name = "USB Audio"
                api.alsa.open.ucm = "true"
                api.alsa.path = "hw:Audio"
                api.alsa.pcm.card = "3"
                api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
                audio.channels = "2"
                audio.position = "FR,FL"
                card.profile.device = "12"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                device.id = "53"
                device.profile.description = "Enceintes"
                device.profile.name = "HiFi: hw:Audio: sink"
                device.routes = "1"
                factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
                media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                device.description = "USB Audio"
                node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFi__hw_Audio__sink"
                node.nick = "Enceintes"
                node.pause-on-idle = "false"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:3:hw:Audio:playback"
                priority.driver = "1000"
                priority.session = "1000"
                factory.id = "18"
                clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
                client.id = "45"
                node.driver = "true"
                factory.mode = "merge"
                audio.adapt.follower = ""
                library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
                object.id = "62"
                object.serial = "63"
                node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
                api.alsa.period-size = "512"
                api.alsa.period-num = "64"
                api.alsa.headroom = "512"
                api.acp.auto-port = "false"
                api.alsa.card = "3"
                api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio3"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.bus-id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:11:00.0-usb-0:6:1.0"
                device.enum.api = "udev"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
                device.name = "alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
                device.nick = "USB Audio"
                device.plugged.usec = "21694171"
                device.product.id = "0x1a52"
                device.product.name = "USB Audio"
                device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
                device.subsystem = "sound"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:0c.0/0000:11:00.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/sound/card3"
                device.vendor.id = "0x0b05"
                device.vendor.name = "ASUSTek Computer, Inc."
                device.string = "3"
        Ports:
                [Out] Speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 200, availability group: Speaker - Output, available)
        Active Port: [Out] Speaker
        Formats:
                pcm

An example of a stream reproducing the issue is :
Sink Input #1899
        Driver: PipeWire
        Owner Module: n/a
        Client: 1898
        Sink: 37
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "48000"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
        Corked: no
        Mute: yes
        Volume: front-left: 45872 /  70% / -9.30 dB,   front-right: 45872 /  70% / -9.30 dB
                balance 0.00
        Buffer Latency: 0 usec
        Sink Latency: 0 usec
        Resample method: PipeWire
        Properties:
                client.api = "pipewire-pulse"
                pulse.server.type = "unix"
                application.name = "DSPGAME.exe"
                application.process.id = "358504"
                application.process.user = "j"
                application.process.host = "cobalt"
                application.process.binary = "wine64-preloader"
                application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
                window.x11.display = ":1"
                application.process.machine_id = "673942026b834c19a71525605f1fb6dd"
                application.process.session_id = "1"
                media.name = "audio stream #1"
                node.rate = "1/48000"
                node.latency = "240/48000"
                stream.is-live = "true"
                node.name = "DSPGAME.exe"
                node.want-driver = "true"
                node.autoconnect = "true"
                media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio"
                adapt.follower.spa-node = ""
                object.register = "false"
                factory.id = "6"
                clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
                factory.mode = "split"
                audio.adapt.follower = ""
                library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
                client.id = "126"
                object.id = "191"
                object.serial = "1899"
                pulse.attr.maxlength = "7680"
                pulse.attr.tlength = "4800"
                pulse.attr.prebuf = "4"
                pulse.attr.minreq = "1920"
                module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:DSPGAME.exe"

The setup as seen from Pipewire
The object for the audio device is described as :
id 62, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "63"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:3:hw:Audio:playback"
        factory.id = "18"
        client.id = "45"
        device.id = "53"
        priority.session = "1000"
        priority.driver = "1000"
        node.description = "Enceintes"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFi__hw_Audio__sink"
        node.nick = "Enceintes"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"

(nick and descriptions are assigned by my wireplumber configuration)
Its properties are like :
  Object: size 1136, type Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props (262146), id Spa:Enum:ParamId:Props (2)
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:volume (65539), flags 00000000
      Float 1.000000
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:mute (65540), flags 00000000
      Bool false
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:channelVolumes (65544), flags 00000000
      Array: child.size 4, child.type Spa:Float
        Float 1.000000
        Float 1.000000
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:channelMap (65547), flags 00000000
      Array: child.size 4, child.type Spa:Id
        Id 3        (Spa:Enum:AudioChannel:FL)
        Id 4        (Spa:Enum:AudioChannel:FR)
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:softMute (65551), flags 00000000
      Bool false
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:softVolumes (65552), flags 00000000
      Array: child.size 4, child.type Spa:Float
        Float 1.000000
        Float 1.000000
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:monitorMute (65548), flags 00000000
      Bool false
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:monitorVolumes (65549), flags 00000000
      Array: child.size 4, child.type Spa:Float
        Float 1.000000
        Float 1.000000
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:params (524289), flags 00000000
      Struct: size 888
        String "monitor.channel-volumes"
        Bool false
        String "channelmix.disable"
        Bool false
        String "channelmix.min-volume"
        Float 0.000000
        String "channelmix.max-volume"
        Float 10.000000
        String "channelmix.normalize"
        Bool false
        String "channelmix.mix-lfe"
        Bool true
        String "channelmix.upmix"
        Bool true
        String "channelmix.lfe-cutoff"
        Float 0.000000
        String "channelmix.fc-cutoff"
        Float 0.000000
        String "channelmix.rear-delay"
        Float 0.000000
        String "channelmix.stereo-widen"
        Float 0.000000
        String "channelmix.hilbert-taps"
        Int 0
        String "channelmix.upmix-method"
        String "none"
        String "resample.quality"
        Int 4
        String "resample.disable"
        Bool false
        String "dither.noise"
        Int 0
        String "dither.method"
        String "none"
        String "debug.wav-path"
        String ""
        String "channelmix.lock-volumes"
        Bool false
  Object: size 1336, type Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props (262146), id Spa:Enum:ParamId:Props (2)
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:device (257), flags 00000000
      String "hw:Audio,1"
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:deviceName (258), flags 00000000
      String ""
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:cardName (261), flags 00000000
      String ""
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:latencyOffsetNsec (65550), flags 00000000
      Long 0
    Prop: key Spa:Pod:Object:Param:Props:params (524289), flags 00000000
      Struct: size 896
        String "audio.channels"
        Int 2
        String "audio.rate"
        Int 0
        String "audio.format"
        String "UNKNOWN"
        String "audio.position"
        String "[ FL, FR ]"
        String "audio.allowed-rates"
        String "[  ]"
        String "api.alsa.period-size"
        Int 512
        String "api.alsa.period-num"
        Int 0
        String "api.alsa.headroom"
        Int 4096
        String "api.alsa.start-delay"
        Int 0
        String "api.alsa.disable-mmap"
        Bool false
        String "api.alsa.disable-batch"
        Bool false
        String "api.alsa.disable-tsched"
        Bool false
        String "api.alsa.use-chmap"
        Bool false
        String "api.alsa.multi-rate"
        Bool true
        String "api.alsa.htimestamp"
        Bool false
        String "api.alsa.htimestamp.max-errors"
        Int 64
        String "latency.internal.rate"
        Int 0
        String "latency.internal.ns"
        Long 0
        String "clock.name"
        String "api.alsa.p-3"


(note in this output I had increased headroom and period-size, which are 0 by default, but this didn't help).
rtkit is installed and loaded
id 1, type PipeWire:Interface:Module/3
        object.serial = "1"
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-rt"

The setup as seen from ALSA
There is a lot of info in /proc/asound/card3. In particular, pcm0p/sub0/hw_params contains :
access: MMAP_INTERLEAVED
format: S32_LE
subformat: STD
channels: 2
rate: 48000 (48000/1)
period_size: 512
buffer_size: 32768

Not sure what else might be revelant. I'm happy to amend the post if anything can be.
Logs and other useful outputs
What probably would be most helpful for diagnosing is the presence of many pipewire messages in the journal when degraded audio is played.
spa.alsa: hw:Audiop: follower avail:770 delay:770 target:640 thr:128, resync (249 suppressed)

This seems to point to buffer underruns I think ? However I tried to increase buffer sizes (what I could find on Internet at least).
The other thing I noticed is that the sink-inputs (as seen by Pulseaudio) seem to use different sample sizes. So far, all streams where the issue doesn't reproduce (VLC, Chrome) use Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz and those where the issue does reproduce use Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz. I can't be sure this is related though, it could just be chance.
What I tried
Of course I tried the obvious : restart pipewire, reboot. I also checked the cables, though the fact that it reliably happens with some programs and never with others shows this can't be a cable issue.
Because crackling is usually associated with buffer underruns, I tried increasing the headroom and period size of the relevant device :
pw-cli s alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFi__hw_Audio__sink Props '{ params = [ "api.alsa.headroom" 4096 ] }'
pw-cli s alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFi__hw_Audio__sink Props '{ params = [ "api.alsa.period-size" 1024 ] }'

This had no effect. Combined with the fact that rtkit is correctly found and that the audio does not stutter, this leads me to believe this is not a buffer underrun issue.
I tried recording audio from alsa using the debug.wav-path param on that same node with pw-cli. When the speaker audio is degraded, the recorded wav file is still fine (I can check by closing the offending program and playing the wav file with VLC).
What now ?
I'm not sure what else to do to diagnose the issue now. The one thing I can think of is writing my own program outputting audio to see if the Sample Specification is indeed related, but even if I find it is, I won't know what to do with that information.
